# JSON HashMap deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to deserialize this JSON "{\"m\":{\"Test\":{\"nombre\":\"jose\",\"apellidos\":\"jose\",\"edad\":30}}}" in to PersonaContainer.

```
    public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int edad;

    ... getters and setters;

}

    public class PersonaContainer {

    private Map m = new HashMap<String,Persona>();

    public Map getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(Map m) {
        this.m = m;
    }   

}
```

Then I, create an Object of persona and put it inside persona container with the next code

```
    public class MyJSONTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map m = new HashMap<String,persona>();

        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setNombre("jose");
        p.setApellidos("jose");
        p.setEdad(30);
        m.put("Test", p);

        PersonaContainer per = new PersonaContainer();
        per.setM(m);

        //convert Map to json string
        try {
            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(per));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // convert json to Map 
        String json = "{\"m\":{\"Test\":{\"nombre\":\"jose\",\"apellidos\":\"jose\",\"edad\":30}}}";
        try {
            PersonaContainer pers = mapper.readValue(json, PersonaContainer.class);
            Persona per1 = (Persona) pers.getM().get("Test");
            System.out.println(per1.getNombre());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }

}
```

After the serialization, I use ObjectMapper to get deserialize JSON in to a PersonaContainer Object, but when I try to obtain "Test" from HashMap "m" and cast it to Person Object i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to persona
    at MyJSONTest.main(MyJSONTest.java:52)
```

any advice please?

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Comment: In `PersonaContainer`, the attribute `m`, its getter and its setter all need to use `Map<String, Persona>`.

Comment: Ok, I get it, it works fine, but if I extend persona from humano @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner

Comment: @Jose See [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263904/deserializing-polymorphic-types-with-jackson)

Comment: Thanks, you where right i add ´@JsonTypeInfo´ and ´@JsonSubTypes´ Annotations and this tells jackson how to deserilize this kind of objects. @Federico Peralta Schaffner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given only

```
private Map m = ...;
```

Jackson has no idea what types you expect for the `Map`'s keys and values. It therefore uses its defaults. For regular objects, it uses `LinkedHashMap`. In other words, it will deserialize

```
{"nombre":"jose","apellidos":"jose","edad":30}
```

into a `LinkedHashMap` instance. When you try to use it as a `Persona`, it fails with the `ClassCastException`.

Instead, don't use raw types. Declare the `Map` with proper generic arguments.

```
private Map<String, Persona> m = ...;
```

Note that Spring will deserialize the corresponding JSON (`m`) into a `LinkedHashMap`, not a `HashMap`. If you want a `HashMap`, declare the field with the type `HashMap`.