# Jackson Inheritance for Attributes

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson, jackson-databind

Is there a way to deserialize the given JSON string with jackson so that the atttribute *attr* is of type *Sub* instead of *Base*?

Json:

```
{
    "x": "yz",
    "attr": {
        "b": "hello",
        "c": "world"
    }
}
```

Java Classes:

```
public class ExampleClass {
  String x;
  Base attr;

  //getter, setter
}


public class Base{  
  String a; 

  //getter, setter 
}

public class Sub extends Base{  
  String b;
  String c;

  //getter, setter
}
```

Comment: Take a look on [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance). If you can not modify this `JSON` and add for example `type` attribute which will define type of given property you can not reuse implemented features but you can always write your own deserialiser.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Fixed Implementation

Following the assumption that you have access to the implementation of `Base`, you can annotate it to always deserialize as the `Sub` implementation using [JsonDeserialize.as()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html#as()).

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = Sub.class)
class Base {
    //etc.
}
```

#### Option 2: Content-based Implementation

Use a field to determine which implementation to deserialize as. See related answer for details: [Deserializing polymorphic types with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24265399/1708977)

#### Option 3: When `Base` Isn't Accessible

This is a way to achieve behavior like option 1 and 2 without having access to the `Base` class implementation. Assuming we want to achieve this with native Jackson, rather than a custom deserializer, we use [Mix-ins](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations). Mix-ins let you add annotations to a model you didn't define, by defining them on a matching signature in a different model.

To define the mix-in to produce Option 1 above:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = Sub.class)
class BaseMixIn { }
```

And to use BaseMixIn, you must modify your ObjectMapper instance:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Base.class, BaseMixIn.class);
```

Simply use the `mapper` like any other ObjectMapper.