# Jackson Polymorphism: Nested Subtypes

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, jackson-databind

Is it possible to use multiple `@JsonSubType` annotations in a nested fashion?

For example, imagine the following classes:

```java
@Data
@JsonSubTypeInfo(include=As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property="species", use=Id.NAME, visible=true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(name="Dog", value=Dog.class)
  @Type(name="Cat", value=Cat.class)
})
public abstract class Animal {
  private String name;
  private String species;
}
```

```java
@Data
@JsonSubTypeInfo(include=As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property="breed", use=Id.NAME, visible=true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(name="Labrador", value=Labrador.class)
  @Type(name="Bulldog", value=Bulldog.class)
})
public abstract class Dog extends Animal {
  private String breed;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Cat extends Animal {
  private boolean lovesCatnip;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Labrador extends Dog {
  private String color;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Bulldog extends Dog {
  private String type; // "frenchy", "english", etc..
}
```

If I use an object mapper, I can successfully map a `Bulldog` to JSON, however, when trying to read the resulting JSON and read it back in, I get an error like the following:

```
Can not construct instance of com.example.Dog abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```

Is it possible to get Jackson to work with such subtyping? Would I need to create a custom deserializer for each subclass?

**EDIT**:

I've modified the classes above slightly from the original posting. I added a `Cat` class and had that and `Dog` extend from `Animal`.

Here is a sample JSON that can be created using the `ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString`:

```
{
  "name": null,
  "species": "Dog",
  "breed": "Bulldog",
  "type": "B-Dog"
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the "breed" property correctly? Could you post how you write and read the JSON, i.e. the code where the exception happens?

Comment: Using the example classes you posted below with some slight modifications (having `Dog` and `Cat` extend `Animal`, and calling `setSpecies`), I printed the `json` and got the following: ```{"name":null,"species":"Dog","breed":"Bulldog","type":"B-Dog"}```

Answer (score 1):

The following works if I use `@JsonTypeInfo` and a similar set up to yours. Maybe your problem is in your deserialization code, so have a look at this:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final Bulldog bulldog = new Bulldog();
        bulldog.setBreed("Bulldog");
        bulldog.setType("B-Dog");

        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        final String json = om.writeValueAsString(bulldog);
        final Dog deserialized = om.readValue(json, Dog.class);
        assertTrue(deserialized instanceof Bulldog);

    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "species", use = Id.NAME, visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @Type(name = "Dog", value = Dog.class),
            @Type(name = "Cat", value = Cat.class)
    })

    public static abstract class Animal {

        private String name;
        private String species;
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "breed", use = Id.NAME, visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @Type(name = "Labrador", value = Labrador.class),
            @Type(name = "Bulldog", value = Bulldog.class)
    })
    public static abstract class Dog {

        private String breed;

        public String getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }

        public void setBreed(final String breed) {
            this.breed = breed;
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Cat {

        private String name;
    }

    public static class Labrador extends Dog {

        private String color;

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(final String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

    public static class Bulldog extends Dog {

        private String type; // "frenchy", "english", etc..

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(final String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

EDITed for the updated question: If you can use the same property (in the following code the hidden property "@class") for the inheritance hierarchy, it works:

```
    @Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    final Bulldog bulldog = new Bulldog();
    // bulldog.setSpecies("Dog");
    // bulldog.setBreed("Bulldog");
    bulldog.setType("B-Dog");

    final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    final String json = om.writeValueAsString(bulldog);
    final Animal deserialized = om.readValue(json, Animal.class);
    assertTrue(deserialized instanceof Bulldog);

}

@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.PROPERTY, use = Id.CLASS, visible = false)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(Dog.class),
        @Type(Cat.class)
})
public static abstract class Animal {

}

@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.PROPERTY, use = Id.CLASS, visible = false)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(name = "Labrador", value = Labrador.class),
        @Type(name = "Bulldog", value = Bulldog.class)
})
public static abstract class Dog
        extends Animal {

}
```

If you want to set the animal type (e.g. to compute species, breed etc.), you could also use this setup:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    final Bulldog bulldog = new Bulldog();
    bulldog.setAnimalType("Bulldog");
    // bulldog.setSpecies("Dog");
    // bulldog.setBreed("Bulldog");
    bulldog.setType("B-Dog");

    final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    final String json = om.writeValueAsString(bulldog);
    System.out.println(json);
    final Animal deserialized = om.readValue(json, Animal.class);
    assertTrue(deserialized instanceof Bulldog);

}

@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "animalType", use = Id.NAME, visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(Dog.class)
})
public static abstract class Animal {

    private String animalType;

    public String getAnimalType() {
        return animalType;
    }

    public void setAnimalType(final String animalType) {
        this.animalType = animalType;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "animalType", use = Id.NAME, visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = Bulldog.class)
})
public static abstract class Dog
        extends Animal {

}

@JsonTypeName("Bulldog")
public static class Bulldog extends Dog {

    private String type; // "frenchy", "english", etc..

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so in your test, you call `om.readValue(json, Dog.class)` - what I'm trying to do would be `om.readValue(json, Animal.class)`. Your `Dog` and `Cat` classes also do not extend `Animal`. If I make those changes (and also call `bulldog.setSpecies("Dog")`) then I get the error that I posted.

Comment: Yes, with that change it is reproducible. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work, however that doesn't produce ideal JSON. Is it possible to solve this problem without the `@class` ? My ideal situation is to have JSON like the following:

```{
  "species": "Dog",
  "breed": "Bulldog",
  "name": "Sparky",
  "type": "English"
}
```

Comment: I guess not, probably using a custom serializer is easier, see maybe also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50013090/6473398

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this such that the following JSON translates to a `Bulldog` object:

```
{
  "species": "Dog",
  "breed": "Bulldog",
  "name": "Sparky",
  "type": "English"
}
```

I used the following code to do this:

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext ctxt, Class<?> instClass, JsonParser p, String msg) throws IOException {
        JsonNode o = p.readValueAsTree();
        JsonNode copy = o.deepCopy();
        JsonNode species = o.get("species");

        if (species != null) {
            Class<? extends Animal> clazz;
            switch (species.asText()) {
                case "Dog":
                    clazz = Dog.class;
                    break;
                case "Cat":
                    clazz = Cat.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    return NOT_HANDLED;
            }

            JsonParser parser = new TreeTraversingParser(copy, p.getCodec());
            parser.nextToken(); // without this an error is thrown about missing "breed" type

            return ctxt.readValue(parser, clazz);
        }

        return NOT_HANDLED;
    }
});
```

I believe there's probably a better way to find the typed class (I noticed that the there is a `cache` in one of the inputs to the `handleMissingInstantiator` method that contains all of the relevant types, that can probably be used to find the type based on name instead of hardcoding values as I'm doing.

Comment: Nice hint ` parser.nextToken();`, could not figure out why the exception came otherwise.