# `@JsonDeserialize` on an interface leads to call stack overflow

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I've got an interface + 2 concrete subclasses, all annotated for Jackson.  The two subclassses work fine independently.  The two subclasses are distinguished by the *name* of a field (K/V pair), not the *value* of some K/V pair.

- Because of that I can't use any of the normal [Jackson PTH](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) features.  **Or can I?? Please let me know.**

I want them serialized w/o any wrapper or injected fields.

The example I'm going to use ([full MCVE gist is here](https://gist.github.com/david-bakin/c6ea81d2755a88989ae72a2a1553b3e0)) is a `BookId` interface where the concrete implementors are `ISBN` and `ASIN`, each with one field.  An example array of `BookId`s would look like this:

```
{ "ids": [
    { "isbn" : "978-0-596-52306-0" },
    { "asin" : "B07QKFQ7QJ" }
]}
```

So `ISBN` and `ASIN` are pretty simple, here's `ISBN` (and `ASIN` is similar with a different validator method):

```
public static class ISBN implements BookId {
    final String isbn;

    @JsonCreator
    public ISBN(@JsonProperty("isbn") String isbn) {
        if (!valid(isbn)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad isbn syntax");
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    boolean valid(String isbn) { return isbn != null && !isbn.isBlank() /* && checksum ok ... */; }
}
```

So trying what I thought was a *proper* approach - simply distinguish the two cases and then call the object mapper appropriately - looks like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = BookId.DeserializerDirectViaJackson.class)
public interface BookId {

    class DeserializerDirectViaJackson extends StdDeserializer<BookId> {
        public DeserializerDirectViaJackson() { this(null); }
        public DeserializerDirectViaJackson(final Class<?> vc) { super(vc); }

        @Override
        public BookId deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            final var om = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
            final var node = (JsonNode) om.readTree(jsonParser);
            if (!node.isObject()) throw new IllegalStateException("expected JSON object");
            if (node.has("isbn")) return om.treeToValue(node, ISBN.class);
            if (node.has("asin")) return om.treeToValue(node, ASIN.class);
            throw new IllegalStateException("expected 'isbn' or 'asin' field");
        }
    }
...
```

where the key lines are:

```
            if (node.has("isbn")) return om.treeToValue(node, ISBN.class);
            if (node.has("asin")) return om.treeToValue(node, ASIN.class);
```

where I look in the `TreeValue` I sucked in for the distinguishing key and then call `ObjectMapper.treeToValue(node, <concreteclass>.class)` to get it parsed properly.

But that leads to infinite recursion, as seen here (top of the call stack):

```
> Task :cli:JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE.main() FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:788)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:786)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.NodeCursor$ObjectCursor.nextToken(NodeCursor.java:214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser.nextToken(TreeTraversingParser.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName(JsonParser.java:1091)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._deserializeContainerNoRecursion(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:536)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:100)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4801)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
    at com.bakinsbits.bookcatalog.JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE$BookId$DeserializerDirectViaJackson.deserialize(JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE.java:58)
    at com.bakinsbits.bookcatalog.JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE$BookId$DeserializerDirectViaJackson.deserialize(JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4801)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2974)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:3438)
    at com.bakinsbits.bookcatalog.JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE$BookId$DeserializerDirectViaJackson.deserialize(JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE.java:60)
    at com.bakinsbits.bookcatalog.JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE$BookId$DeserializerDirectViaJackson.deserialize(JacksonInterfaceCustomDeserializerMCVE.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4801)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2974)
```

and so on and so forth.

**So, question:** Why does it do that and - more important - how do I make it work?

For comparision (and to show I did the work) the following deserializer *does* work but has the (major) disadvantage that I basically have to parse & validate the concrete subclasses myself.  Doable for this toy example, but not so much for a real use case.

```
    class DeserializerHomegrown extends StdDeserializer<BookId> {
        public DeserializerHomegrown() { this(null); }
        public DeserializerHomegrown(final Class<?> vc) { super(vc); }

        @Override
        public BookId deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            final var om = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
            final var node = (JsonNode) om.readTree(jsonParser);
            if (!node.isObject()) throw new IllegalStateException("expected JSON object");
            if (node.has("isbn")) return new ISBN(getValueNode(node, "isbn"));
            if (node.has("asin")) return new ASIN(getValueNode(node, "asin"));
            throw new IllegalStateException("expected 'isbn' or 'asin' field");
        }

        String getValueNode(JsonNode node, String fieldName) {
            final var field = node.get(fieldName);
            if (field == null) return null;
            if (!field.isValueNode()) throw new IllegalStateException("%s field is not JSON value".formatted(fieldName));
            return field.asText();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduce specific subtypes of one type related with the presence of specific properties with the use of [`JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) annotation and its deduction system:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(ASIN.class), @Type(ISBN.class)})
public interface BookId {}

@Data
public class ISBN implements BookId {
    private String isbn;
}

@Data
public class ASIN implements BookId {
    private String asin;
}
```

In this case the classes implementing the `BookId` interface can be identified by the presence or not of their own asin and isbn properties, so you can deserialize an array of `BookId` like below:

**Input:**

```
{ "ids": [
    { "isbn" : "978-0-596-52306-0" },
    { "asin" : "B07QKFQ7QJ" }
]}
```

An example based on the json input provided:

```
JsonNode ids = mapper.readTree(json).at("/ids");
BookId[] bookIds = mapper.treeToValue(ids, BookId[].class);
//ok, it prints [ISBN(isbn=978-0-596-52306-0), ASIN(asin=B07QKFQ7QJ)]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bookIds));
```

Comment: Wow!  I think `Id.DEDUCTION` is new since the last time I looked at `JsonTypeInfo`.  I'll look into how it works (i.e., how smart it is ...)

Comment: (It could use more documentation  right there in the Javadoc for either JsonTypeInfo or JsonTypeInfo.ID - but there _is_ documentation available, e.g., [_Jackson 2.12 Most Wanted (1/5): Deduction-Based Polymorphism_](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-1-5-deduction-based-polymorphism-c7fb51db7818), also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66167492/751579))

Comment: @davidbak Glad to have helped, at [jsontype](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/tree/2.16/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype) you can find many examples.

Comment: Works great.  Obviously works with Java 17+ records too (vs. `@Data`).